# read file from user input in bash and store in variable

Tags: bash, shell

Team,

looks simple but am unable to catch it. Am trying to read a file from user and store its contents into variable. My echo is working as its printing the file but my cat is not working.

```
read -p "specify the file to read nodes from: " file
echo $file

file_contents=$(cat $file | awk -F ',' '{print $1}')

for item in $file_contents
do
echo $item
done;
```

output

```
$HOME\backup\file.log

no such file
cat $HOME\backup\file.log
```

expected output

```
\home\users\backup\file.log

item1
item2
item3
```

Comment: How are you running the script?

Comment: I figured out the issue.. I cannot input the filepath as $HOME.. its not expanding it. when i enter absolute path its working.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `for` there, BTW. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Answer (score 1):

The file with should be entered with absolute path and not $HOME.

so providing whole file path worked for me.

if there is a way I can use $HOME. Please advise.